# How do I translate a C union into Delphi?

Tags: delphi

```c
typedef struct _FILE_OBJECTID_INFORMATION {
    LONGLONG FileReference;
    UCHAR ObjectId[16];
    union {
        struct {
            UCHAR BirthVolumeId[16];
            UCHAR BirthObjectId[16];
            UCHAR DomainId[16];
        } DUMMYSTRUCTNAME;
        UCHAR ExtendedInfo[48];
    } DUMMYUNIONNAME;
} FILE_OBJECTID_INFORMATION, *PFILE_OBJECTID_INFORMATION;
```

How to translate such a union to Delphi?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The Pascal equivalent of a C `union` is known as a [variant record](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Structured_Types#Variant_Parts_in_Records).

> A record type can have a variant part, which looks like a **case**
>   statement. The variant part must follow the other fields in the record
>   declaration.
>
> To declare a record type with a variant part, use the following
>   syntax:
>
> ```
> type recordTypeName = record
>   fieldList1: type1;
>    ...
>   fieldListn: typen;
> case tag: ordinalType of
>   constantList1: (variant1);
>    ...
>   constantListn: (variantn);
> end;
> ```
>
> The first part of the declaration - up to the reserved word **case** - is
>   the same as that of a standard record type. The remainder of the
>   declaration - from **case** to the optional final semicolon - is called
>   the variant part. In the variant part,
>
> - *tag* is optional and can be any valid identifier. If you omit *tag*, omit the colon (:) after it as well.
> - *ordinalType* denotes an ordinal type.
> - Each *constantList* is a constant denoting a value of type *ordinalType*, or a comma-delimited list of such constants. No value can
>     be represented more than once in the combined *constantLists*.
> - Each *variant* is a semicolon-delimited list of declarations resembling the *fieldList: type* constructions in the main part of the
>     record type. That is, a variant has the form:
>
>   fieldList1: type1;
>      ...
>     fieldListn: typen;
>
> where each *fieldList* is a valid identifier or comma-delimited list of
>   identifiers, each type denotes a type, and the final semicolon is
>   optional. The types must not be long strings, dynamic arrays, variants
>   (that is, Variant types), or interfaces, nor can they be structured
>   types that contain long strings, dynamic arrays, variants, or
>   interfaces; but they can be pointers to these types.
>
> Records with variant parts are complicated syntactically but
>   deceptively simple semantically. The variant part of a record contains
>   several variants which share the same space in memory. You can read or
>   write to any field of any variant at any time; but if you write to a
>   field in one variant and then to a field in another variant, you may
>   be overwriting your own data. The tag, if there is one, functions as
>   an extra field (of type *ordinalType*) in the non-variant part of the
>   record.

---

As for the rest, it's pretty routine: `LONGLONG` is a 64 bit integer, and `UCHAR` is `unsigned char`, or `AnsiChar` in Delphi.

```
type
  TFileObjectIDInformation = record
    FileReference: Int64;
    ObjectID: array[0..15] of AnsiChar;
    case Integer of
    0:
      (
        BirthVolumeId: array[0..15] of AnsiChar;
        BirthObjectId: array[0..15] of AnsiChar;
        DomainId: array[0..15] of AnsiChar;
      );
    1:
      (ExtendedInfo: array[0..47] of AnsiChar);
  end;
```

It's possible that `Byte` may be more appropriate than `AnsiChar`. It's a bit hard to tell of course because C, unlike Pascal, doesn't have separate types for `Byte` and `AnsiChar`. But these arrays look to me as though they would be read as text so my guess is that `AnsiChar` would be more appropriate.

Comment: @Astaroth Done. Thank you. I always get confused by that!

Answer (score 5):

*Similar* structure can be found in [JEDI API Lib](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jedi-apilib/):

```
  _FILE_OBJECTID_BUFFER = record

    //
    //  This is the portion of the object id that is indexed.
    //

    ObjectId: array [0..15] of BYTE;

    //
    //  This portion of the object id is not indexed, it's just
    //  some metadata for the user's benefit.
    //

    case Integer of
      0: (
        BirthVolumeId: array [0..15] of BYTE;
        BirthObjectId: array [0..15] of BYTE;
        DomainId: array [0..15] of BYTE);
      1: (
        ExtendedInfo: array [0..47] of BYTE);
  end;
```

Comment: That's a different struct. Take a look at the names. That struct differs in that it does not have the first field that can be found in the question.